# XmlUtil.serialize(root) is changing void tags to self closing tags

Tags: html, xml, groovy, xhtml

Here is a groovy snippet with an empty div tag (`<div></div>`):

```
import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def HTML_STRING = '''
    <html>
    <div></div>
    <div>Some text</div>
    </html>
  '''

def xhtml = DOMBuilder.parse(new StringReader(HTML_STRING))
def root = xhtml.documentElement

XmlUtil.serialize(root, System.out)
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <div/>
    <div>Some text</div>
    </html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It appears that `XmlUtil.serialize` self-closes void tags - I don't want that. Anybody has an idea how to disable this feature?

Thank you.

Uros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XmlNodePrinter`, so long as you switch to XmlParser:

```
def xhtml = new XmlParser().parseText( HTML_STRING )

new XmlNodePrinter( expandEmptyElements:true ).print( xhtml )
```

Comment: I ended up using jSoup... now I am having problems with escaping. Thanks for your help though.